# Showing that holomorphic maps do not preserve convexity

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to show that the image of the function $f(z)=(z+2)^4$ from the unit disk in the complex plane is not convex but i can not seem to figure out an explicit example to show this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome on math.stackexchange :) If you have a math formula, you can put dollar signs on both sides to make it look pretty (I have already put them for you now). I guess it makes sense to draw some picture to imagine what is going on (remember that raising a complex number to the fourth power stretches the radial part and multiplies the angle by $4$).

Comment: Here is a hint: Plot $t \mapsto f(e^{it})$ for $t \in [0, 2 \pi)$.